# Access Control Template Controls in Wpf?

Tags: wpf

How to access the Buttons inside the stackpanel(Control Template)??  Means i have to make those buttons as single button object.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button" x:Key="temp" x:Name="hotel">
        <StackPanel x:Name="service">

                <Button Content="1" Width="30" Height="30" Name="tempbtn1"/>
                <Button Content="2" Width="30" Height="30" Name="tempbtn2"/>
                <Button Content="3" Width="30" Height="30" Name="tempbtn3"/>
                <Button Content="4" Width="30" Height="30" Name="tempbtn4"/>
            </StackPanel>

    </ControlTemplate>      
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="txttype" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Room Type" Width="120" Height="30" Margin="10 0 0 0"/> 
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Submit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="9,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click"/> 

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="Deluxe">
        <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="1" Width="60" Height="60" Template="{StaticResource temp}"/>
        <Button Margin="10 0 0 0" Content="2" x:Name="btn2" Width="60" Height="60" Template="{StaticResource temp}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: What are you trying to Achieve? Splitting one Button into 4 Buttons makes no sense to me. Please explain yourself

Comment: If i give 1 in textbox then the first button of the control template of button(named as btn1)  should be changed its background color..

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the exact requirement of you.But i hope following information will be useful to you.

General syntax to get the elements that are declared inside the control template is:

```
var template = controlName.Template;
var myControl = (typeofthecontrol)template.FindName("MyControlName",controlName);
```

In your sample,

```
var template = btn1.Template;
var myControl = (Button)template.FindName("tempbtn1", MyList);
```